# How to make a responsive iFrame because the contents doesn't fit inside my iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have an iFrame that fetch data from the database, but when I load my iFrame, The picture from its content is so big that it doesn't fit inside the iFrame. How do I fix this?

Index.html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <iframe src="" frameborder="0" id="news">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Script.js:

```
function displayNews(news) {
    const breadcrumbActive = $(".breadcrumb-item.active");
    const newsTitle = $(".news-title");
    const newsDate = $(".news-date");
    const iFrame = $("#news");

    const title = news.Title;
    const date = news.Dates;

    breadcrumbActive.text(title);
    newsTitle.text(title);
    newsDate.text(date);

    iFrame
      .css({
        width: "100%",
        height: "100px",
        "margin-block": "10px",
        border: "none",
      })
      .prop("scrolling", "no");

    let MessageHTML = "";
    MessageHTML = news.Message; //The image is located in here as well as the text

    const newsFile = new Blob([MessageHTML], { type: "text/html" });

    iFrame.attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(newsFile));

    iFrame.on("load", function () {
      const height = iFrame.contents().height();
      iFrame.height(height);
    });
  }
```

Comment: How do you want to fix the issue? Do you want to make the iframe bigger, or perhaps scale the image down? Or some other way?

Comment: @Teemu I want to scale the image down to fit it inside the iFrame

Comment: Tried to add iFrame.contents().find("img").css({
        "max-width": "100%",
        "max-height": "100%"
      }); after IFrame.height(height); May be it will fit inside the IFrame.

Comment: @HiteshPadhara It did not worked for me